# CardView and recycleView duplicate error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi Im trying to use cardview and recycle view in my android studio project. When i put cardview in to my dependencies it works fine. However, when i add the recycle view in to dependencies an error comes up. 
can someone tells me how to solve this issue?

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/Parse-1.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.2.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

the error code:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/jonathan34c/AndroidstudioProjects/Cue_business1/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/jonathan34c/AndroidstudioProjects/Cue_business1/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your build folder and then rebuild it. And add dependencies in your app gradle as

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Try this might help you.